# SQL loop. I want to iterate through a loop containing SELECT results

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

From a table with column structure (parent, child) I need:

1. For a particular parent I need all children.
2. From the result of (1) I need the children's children too.

For example for parent=1:

```
    parent|child  parent|child   parent|child
    1      a        a     d        b      f
           b              e               g
```

Comment: Do you want 3 separate recordset or all result in one recordset?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Can you post the parent|child input data which would yield your example result? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am using DB2 and i need all results in one recordset

Answer (score 0):

This gets you the information you say you want, I think. Two columns: child and grandchild (if any, or else NULL). Not sure if it's the schema you'd like, since you don't specify. You may add JOINs to increase the recursion depth.

```
select t1.child, t2.child
from T as t1 left join T as t2
on t1.child = t2.parent
where t1.parent = 1
```

This works on SQLite; I think it's quite standard. Regarding schema if this one doesn't serve you, hopefully it may give you ideas; or else please specify more.

Comment: This is not accurate when the relationship has more than 3 levels, for example A has child B, and B has child C, The question actually is a common scenario that can be solved using recursion.